# How to update Tag Data using itunes match?

Tags: itunes, itunes-match

I have a lot of music files, and the tag information of some music files is wrong or missing.

I tried to use itunes match to match these music files, the effect is good, they are displayed as "matched".
but the tag information has not changed, is there a way to update the Tag Data by the itunes match service ?
as they are marked as "matched", I think apple  itunes should know the right tag information
Thanks